# Conda can not take multiple arguments?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, miniconda

I am in a conda base environment, which is using Python3.8. I want to create an environment for tensorflow 1.15 and python 2.7, so I did:

```
conda create -n tf-py2 tensorflow-gpu=1.15.0 python=2.7
```

This successfully created environment with tensorflow, but the python is still 3.8, not 2.7. However, this creates p2.7 environment:

```
conda create -n tf-gpu-py2 python=2.7
```

which means it can't take multi-arguments. Is this normal?

Comment: Tensorflow doesn't work with Python 2.7, actually it's support start from Python 3.6. For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements). Thanks!